# Targeting inside a loop?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#questions .question").each(function() {}
```

`.question` is an li, inside the `.question` li is another list with a class `.answers`, each with an li of class `.answer`.

I've tried this to target them inside the above loop but no luck:

```
$(this).$(".answer").each(function() {}
```

Does anyone know how to target each answer li within the loop using this?

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).find('.answer')` or `$('.answer', this)`

They are equivalent. From jQuery source:

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)`:

```
$("#questions .question").each(function() {
    console.log($(this)); // each .question li
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#questions .question").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".answer").each( function() {
        //code here
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context to apply the selector to. In this case passing `this` will achieve what you want:

```
$("#questions .question").each(function() {
    $(".answer", this).each(function() { // Pass `this` as the context
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#questions .question").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).find('.answer').each(function(index, element) {
        /* do stuff */
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/